# SBT and the Smartcloud API

Tags: ibm-sbt

Will code that I write using the SBT SDK using a Connections environment port to a SmartCloud environment? Similarly, will code I develop using the SBT SDK for the IBM Collaboration QuickStart image port to a SmartCloud environment?
I'm still a bit confused about the differences between the Connections API and the Smartcloud API. Does the SBT wrapper code handle the differences, if any, for you?
Thanks!
Cindy

Comment: great, question, essentially there are some differences, I'll ask an architect to respond

Answer (score 1):

so there are two types of differences between the Connections applications on SmartCloud and On-Premise:

1. SmartCloud has older versions of certain application e.g. Communities. The API's however are backward compatible so code written with the SDK Java/JS API's will work against both environments. Were the underlying REST API's behave differently the SDK API's normalise the differences.
2. The Profiles application is fundamentally different between SmartCloud and On-Premise. For this application we provide two separate Java/JS API's because the differences between the applications (and their associated REST API's) is significant. We do not provide code to handle this differences, this would be complex to build in a generic way. The good news is that this is only a short term problem as the Profiles application on SmartCloud is due to be upgraded (I don't have the details on when this will happen).

Hope this helps
Mark

Comment: Thanks Mark. That clarifies the differences btwn the APIs. So, I assume then for SmartCloud profiles I would not be able to use the IBM Collaboration QuickStart image but can use the SBT playground on Greenhouse using the SmartCloud (or SmartCloud stage) env selected?